# Leaflet: using mouseover and opacity get a conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps, leaflet

I created a function to mouse over a colorless layer and everything. So far so good, and also created a function to go back as it was before the mouse. But when I use the opacity, the reset function does not return to normal and leaves the opacity in the default state (0.7) and not in the state it is in at the moment.

Function to mouseouver:

```
function highlightFeature_stComerciais(e) {
            layerStComerciais = e.target;

            layerStComerciais.setStyle({
                weight: 5,
                color: '#666',
                dashArray: ''
            });

            info.update(layerStComerciais.feature.properties);
        }
```

function to mouseout

```
function resetHighlight_stComerciais(e) {
            setoresComerciaisOverlay.resetStyle(e.target);
            info.update();
        }
```

opacity:

```
$('#sldOpacity').on('change', function(){
            $('#image-opacity').html(this.value);
            setoresComerciaisOverlay.setStyle({ fillOpacity: this.value })  
        });
```

The default opacity is 0.7, assuming I put 0 of opacity, when I do mouse over the Layer all right, but when I mouse out it returns to 0.7 and I do not want this. Why my reset doesnt work how I want? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you build your vector layers using GeoJSON data and [`L.geoJSON`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson) factory, that returns a Leaflet GeoJSON Layer Group.

The [`resetStyle`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-resetstyle) method on that group re-applies the [`style`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-style) that was applied at the time of creation of that group, or the default one if you did not provide style:

> Resets the given vector layer's style to the original GeoJSON style, useful for resetting style after hover events.

If you later change the style of one or all of the vector layers in that group, it will be therefore overridden when you use `resetStyle`, and the initial style will be applied.

An easy workaround is simply to modify the GeoJSON Layer Group's `style` option as well. However, it will affect *all* its child layers.

```js
group.options.style = newStyle;
```

Another solution would be to record the new style of each vector layer, and use that recorded value when you want to restore the previous state, instead of using the group's `resetStyle` method.

```js
var map = L.map("map").setView([48.85, 2.35], 12);

var geojson = {
  type: "Feature",
  geometry: {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [2.35, 48.85]
  }
};

var point;
var startStyle = {
  color: "red"
};
var newStyle = {
  color: 'green'
};

var group = L.geoJSON(geojson, {
  style: startStyle,
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    point = L.circleMarker(latlng);
    assignStyle(point, startStyle);
    return point;
  }
}).addTo(map);

// Record the style to the individual vector layer if necessary.
function assignStyle(leafletLayer, newStyle) {
  leafletLayer.setStyle(newStyle);
  leafletLayer._recordedStyle = newStyle;
}

// When desired, apply the style that has been previously recorded.
function reassignStyle(leafletLayer) {
  leafletLayer.setStyle(leafletLayer._recordedStyle);
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Either use the wrapper function that records the new style…
  //assignStyle(point, newStyle);

  // Or simply modify the group's style option, if it is acceptable affecting all child layers.
  point.setStyle(newStyle);
  group.options.style = newStyle;
});

group.on({
  mouseover: function(e) {
    e.target.setStyle({
      color: 'blue'
    });
  },
  mouseout: function(e) {
    //reassignStyle(e.layer);
    group.resetStyle(e.layer);
  }
});

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 100px"></div>
<button id="button">Change color to Green…</button>
<p>…then mouseover and mouseout</p>
```

Comment: Don't work, I guess that is some more simple. Is just, example, the default opacity is 0.7, assuming I put 0 of opacity, when I do mouse over the Layer all right, but when I mouse out it returns to 0.7 and I do not want this. I believe be a detail. Take a look, please. All my code is here: https://github.com/eltonsantos/leaflet-tests/blob/master/teste3/index.html please, help me

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question body if the above does not work in your case.

Comment: It turns out that I did not understand very well, because I found it very complex. I believe it to be a simpler thing to solve. However the simple insertion of group.options.style = newStyle; I do not know if it solves my problem.